# how to publish the flutter app with python file

Tags: python, flutter, http, publish

**Hello**
I have successfully connected the python file/script with flutter app by `http` request. Now I need to make my app live on google play store, where should I keep my python file so it will be connected with flutter app and works for all users. 
Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Is your python file running its script locally or with online server? Means is your script fetching data from any server or just locally?

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar my python script is running locally

Comment: Then you can save it inside your assets folder. And when you release your app it will bundle up inside your apk.

Comment: Then which url/link should I use for connection, as for now i'm using a link/url of my local server like http://172.0.0.0:5000/rout  ?

Comment: This is what I was asking. If you are using your localhost then you need to host your script to an online server so it's globally available to call. You cant put your python file in assets in this case. Use Heroku to host your python script.

Comment: ok thanks, one more thing is there a way I can run python script(in flask) offline or without using a server?